# Type inference workaround for generic function

Tags: f#, type-inference

Given the following parametric type

```
type SomeDU2<'a,'b> = 
    | One of 'a
    | Two of 'a * 'b
```

I have to functions that check if the given param is the respective union case without regard to params

```
let checkOne x = 
    match x with
    | One _ -> true
    | _ -> false

let checkTwo x = 
    match x with
    | Two _ -> true
    | _ -> false
```

This works pretty nice and as expected

```
let oi = checkOne (One 1)
let os = checkOne (One "1")
let tis = checkTwo (Two (1, "1"))
let tsi = checkTwo (Two ("1", 1))
```

I can switch the types as I like.
Now However I like to combine those two functions into one creation function

```
let makeUC () = (checkOne, checkTwo)
```

and then instantiate like this

```
let (o,t) = makeUC ()
```

only it gives me this error message now

```
Value restriction. The value 'o' has been inferred to have generic type
    val o : (SomeDU2<'_a,'_b> -> bool)    
Either make the arguments to 'o' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
val o : (SomeDU2<obj,obj> -> bool)
```

Actually I dont want that - nor do I need that.
Probably its a instance of missing higher kinded types in F# 
Is there a way around this?

**Edit**

Actually me question wasnt complety as per @johns comment below.
Obviously I can do the following

```
let ro1 = o ((One 1) : SomeDU2<int,int>)
let rt1 = t (Two (1,2))
```

which then will *backwards* infer `o` and `t` to be of type `SomeDU2<int,int> -> bool` (I find this backwards inference very strange thou). The problem then is that `o` wont allow for the below anymore.

```
let ro2 = o ((One "1") : SomeDU2<string,int>)
```

So I'd have to instantiate a specific `o` instance for every combination of generic parameters of `SomeDU2`.

Comment: Two options: either do what the error message says, or if you use `o` the message will probably go away

Comment: @JohnPalmer added some more info due to your comment

Comment: How are you planning to use a tuple of functions ? Seems awkward. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @asibahi effectively this https://github.com/robkuz/fs.UnionCase

Answer (score 3):

You would run into the value restriction even without the tuple:

```
let o = (fun () -> checkOne)()
```

If you need the results of invoking a function to be applicable to values of any type, then one solution would be to create instances of a nominal type with a generic method:

```
type DU2Checker =
    abstract Check : SomeDU2<'a,'b> -> bool

let checkOne = { 
    new DU2Checker with 
    member this.Check(x) = 
        match x with 
        | One _ -> true 
        | _ -> false }

let checkTwo = { 
    new DU2Checker with 
    member this.Check(x) = 
        match x with 
        | Two _ -> true 
        | _ -> false }

let makeUC() = checkOne, checkTwo

let o,t = makeUC()

let false = o.Check(Two(3,4))
```